# Change tintColor for selected state in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, tintcolor, accessoryview

I have a UITableViewCell which has a custom icon for the accessoryView, set as follows:

```
    let customDetailDisclosureButton = UIButton.init(type: .detailDisclosure)
    customDetailDisclosureButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "custom")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    cell.accessoryView = customDetailDisclosureButton
```

However, when the cell is selected, the custom icon is hidden:

[image: TableCell with hidden accessoryView]

I've tried to change the tint color of the accessoryView to white when the cell is selected, but its not changing (see above). Here's what I've tried to do.

```
func tableView(_: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    
    print("Will select row at: \(indexPath)")
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    selectedCell?.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    
    if let accessoryButton = selectedCell?.accessoryView as? UIButton {
            
        // !! Doesn't change the tint color !!
        accessoryButton.tintColor = .white
    }

    guard let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
        print("No existing selected row at: \(indexPath)")
        return indexPath
    }
    
    
    // The same cell has been selected twice
    if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
        print("Same cell selected twice: \(indexPath)")
        return indexPath
    }
        
    print("Resetting to default \(selectedIndexPath)")
    // Reset to default
    let previousSelectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath)
    previousSelectedCell?.textLabel?.textColor = .black
    previousSelectedCell?.accessoryView?.tintColor = .systemBlue
    
    return indexPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to setup a UIImageView with two images. One for the normal state and one for the highlighted state. Tint the two images with the appropriate colors as desired.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "custom")?.withTintColor(.label, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
let highlighted = UIImage(named: "custom")?.withTintColor(.systemBackground, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
let customAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: image, highlightedImage: highlighted)
cell.accessoryView = customAccessoryView
```

That's all you need. Now you can remove all other code related to trying to change the accessory view's tintColor. When a row is selected the highlighted image will automatically be applied and when a row is not selected the normal image will automatically be applied.